# understanding the anonymous function scope and return value

Tags: javascript

I have a function the receives two ints, I want another variable to be initialized with the larger one.

this is the code part:

```js
function findCommonDev(num1, num2) {
  var res = ((num1, num2) => {
    if (num1 > num2) {
      return num1;
    } else {
      return num2;
    }
  });
  console.log(res);
  }
  findCommonDev(10,12)
```

Now the questions arising from this are not related to the specific code.

1. the console.log(res) prints '[function: res]' I would expect res to have the value of the bigger int passed to the function.
2. I'm writing in VSC and the arguments are not marked as being used meaning that there is shadowing of num1 and num2 - why?
3. how do I solve this elegantly?

Comment: the returned function is the function, you should call.

Answer (score 3):

You need to called the function and pass `num1` and `num2` as parameters.

```js
function findCommonDev(num1, num2) {
  var res = ((num1, num2) => {
    if (num1 > num2) {
      return num1;
    } else {
      return num2;
    }
  })(num1,num2);
  console.log(res);
}

findCommonDev(4,6)
```

Also notice that if you don't pass `num1` and `num2` the code won't work because inside the the function `num1` and `num2` are local variables and not the variables of outer function.

> The expected arguments of function are just like local variables. They are created whether parameters are passed or not.

Comment: Yh this is because the values in findCommonsDev are not passed straight into res.

Comment: OK, this is important.... it works. did I forget to call the functions?

Comment: @TomAbarba  Yes the problem was you were not calling the function. Also see the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Beside the returning of a new function (which is the real function for giving the wanted value), you could just take the max value.

```js
function findCommonDev(num1, num2) {
    var res = Math.max(num1, num2);
    console.log(res);
}

findCommonDev(3, 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving to console a function reference. However, of you want to run function, then specify parameters:

```js
function findCommonDev(num1, num2) {
    var res = ((num1, num2) => {
      if (num1 > num2) {
        return num1;
      } else {
        return num2;
      }
    });
    return res(num1, num2);
    };


    console.log(findCommonDev(1,2));
```